# FSPagerview - Is it possible to use this inside a repeating cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

( I followed the tutorial here : https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView#implement_fspagerviewdatasource )

and it works when the pagerview is not inside a tableview or if the tableview is static but fails if the pagerview is in a dynamic table.

This is the code

```
    @IBOutlet weak var pagerView: FSPagerView! {
        didSet {
            self.pagerView.register(FSPagerViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
    }

    public func numberOfItems(in pagerView: FSPagerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, cellForItemAt index: Int) -> FSPagerViewCell {
        let cell = pagerView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)
        cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "four")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "..."
        return cell
    }
```

and whenever i run this, it crashes with

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[test.HomeTableViewController numberOfItemsInPagerView:]: unrecognized
selector sent to instance 0x7fb644e1dfc0'
***
```

Can somebody help me or point me in the right direction on how to use this inside a dynamic tableview? (or maybe some other way to have a sliding banner inside a dynamic cell of a tableview?)

Comment: post viewDidLoad too its not enough info to solve it.  you have not posted anything regarding tableView how we can solve it?  i think its only an issue of statement hierarchy post some more code

Comment: you can also post whole controller by hiding your private data and placing example data over there.

Comment: this error is not related to pager view, in dynamic tableview you need to configure pagerview in `tableView(_:, willDisplay cell:, at:)` method

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Thanks for trying to help. But the issue was not because of that. Normally we always add information about elements inside a custom cell in the custom cell class but in this case, it didnt work but adding the same information on the main tableviewcontroller class worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Incase someone gets the same error in the future.
Normally we always add data/information about cell content in the cell class rather than the tableview call.

But here, adding the relevant codes in cell class gives the above mentioned error.

To solve this issue simply add this in the tableview class

```
class TableViewControllers: UIViewController,FSPagerViewDelegate,
FSPagerViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


// MARK: - PagerView
    func numberOfItems(in pagerView: FSPagerView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, cellForItemAt index: Int) -> FSPagerViewCell {
                let cell = pagerView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)
        cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "four")
      //  cell.textLabel?.text = "..."
        return cell
    }
```

and on the cell class add this

```
    @IBOutlet weak var pagerView: FSPagerView! {
        didSet {
            self.pagerView.register(FSPagerViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
    }
```

and connect it to your FSPagerView.

Regards.

Comment: I have the same issue, will you give your mail ID if possible I will connect over there.

Comment: how to call custom collection cell class in FSPageview tableview cell class